# Difference between the MacBook CPUs

Tags: cpu, macbook, benchmarking

I have an old 2011 13-inch MacBook Pro and I am thinking to buy a new one. I am wondering if the difference between the CPUs is different. I checked the benchmarks [here](https://browser.geekbench.com/macs/278).

> MacBook Pro (13-inch Early 2011) Intel Core i5-2415M @ 2.3 GHz (2
>   cores) Score: **486**
>
> MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2019) Intel Core i5-8279U @ 2.4 GHz (4 cores)
>   Score: **961**       MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2019) Intel Core i5-8257U
>   @ 1.4 GHz (4 cores) Score: **940**
>
> MacBook Pro (15-inch Mid 2019) Intel Core i7-9750H @ 2.6 GHz (6 cores)
>   Score: **1037**

Does that means that the new CPUs are only around 2 times faster than the old 2011 CPUs? The difference between the 1.4GHz i5 CPU and the other ones seems very small. Do you think there is a significant overall difference? I will need the laptop mainly for programming (Xcode, react, Tensorflow).

Comment: It's not all about clock speed, it's also about Level 1 & 2 cache, support for DDR4 memory, chipset support for USB3, CPU instructions etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the single core results. When you click on the Multi-core it changes to:

i5-2415M 1060
i7-9750H 5442

So if what you are planning on doing is single-threaded you are correct, the new MacBook will be roughly twice as fast. Anything multi-threaded will be a lot faster, depending on the workload.

Keep in mind Geekbench is a general benchmark. You can read what the test includes in this [pdf](https://www.geekbench.com/doc/geekbench5-cpu-workloads.pdf) , I suggest the detailed test report and try to check what is relevant to your use case.

And a final remark: Tensorflow is a lot faster when it runs on the GPU so you might want to check the graphics card as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I will need the laptop mainly for programming (Xcode, react, Tensorflow).

So keep your old one.

You can't judge only with these score: some benchmarks are targeting "single thread performances", others "multi-thread", others "floating point", etc...
You should select the benchmark that are the more related to you domain of usage.

For programming, i think you should better look at:

- Numbers of core (if your build process is able to use several processes).
- Storage: SSD or Magnetic ?
- Display: Full HD ?

Cause the "raw power" of CPU won't be a big issue if your main goal is programming.